# better way to manipulate strings to create a new column pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a column of names e.g. GBR_1, GBR_2, FRA_1, FRA_2, etc and I want to create a column with just GBR, GBR, FRA, FRA, etc . I currently do the following:

```
df['Country'] = [df['Team'][i].partition('_')[0] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Does not seem like the best way to go about it especially if the partition character may change e.g. could be a '-' or a '_' or a ':'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if want only uppercase character with `[A-Z]+` or if also lowercase use `[A-Za-z]+`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['GBR_1', 'GBR_2', 'FRA:1', 'FRA-2']})
df['Team'] = df['Team'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)', expand=False)
print (df)
  Team
0  GBR
1  GBR
2  FRA
3  FRA
```